# Missing Crypto-Key in firefox push notifications

Tags: php, firefox, curl

I am developing push notifications for Mozilla Firefox browser and when sending a push from my server with cURL I get the following error - Missing Crypro-Key.
As far as I understand I should get this key with the following JS code:

```
var key = subscription.getKey('p256dh');
```

but what should I do with it? Should I send it to my server and somehow use it? I tried to insert it into my $url parameter which is user in cURL:

```
$url = 'https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/$key.$registrationIDs[0];
```

from everywhere but no push message was received. By the way when I use it I receive no error messages though no success one received too, just empty array. Any ideas would be welcome. Thank You.

UPD_1: Seeing this question [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833018/how-can-i-leverage-subscription-getkey-in-service-workers) I found out that for Firefox it is possible to send pushes with encrypted payload as well as to fetch messages directly from server as it is done in Chrome. In Firefox now I use the second variant without and Crypto-Keys, just set the $url in here:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
```

to

```
$url = 'https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/'.$yourregid;
```

and $headers parameter here

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

to this

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf8','TTL: 600');
```

Now does anyone have an example how to send a push to Firefox with encrypted payload in PHP? I found an example here [LINK](https://github.com/edmoz/push-notification-test/blob/master/main.js) but it is for JS. Thank You

Comment: does you actual code share this typo? (fixed here):  $url = `'https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/'.$key.$registrationIDs[0];`

Comment: yes, it is assumed to be variable $key. I tried to put it before $registrationIDs[0] or after, still no luck((